# Android app fails to make ajax calls to HTTPS after signing

Tags: android, ajax, ssl, https, phonegap-build

I'm developing an Android app with PhoneGap Build and I experienced an annoying problem:

I make ajax GET calls to our HTTPS server, and it works without any problems if I just package a debug version of the app.

As soon as I sign the application with my key, and try out the app on my phone or an emulator, it fails with the following error:

```
NetworkError: A Network error occured.
```

If I change all the https addresses, to http, package it and sign it the same way, it suddenly starts working again.

To sum up:

UNSIGNED apk : - https & http both work

SIGNED apk : only http works.

I want to clarify, that the android permissions are unchanged, only the http**s** is the difference.

Comment: your phone doesn't trust your server certificate, when the app is unsigned it works because debugable is set to true and ignores bad certificates, when you sign it, debugable changes to false

Comment: Thank you for the reply! Is there any workaround? other than getting a new server certificate... ?

Comment: No, as you are using phonegap build, you can't edit the native code. If you switch to local develompent, there are a class that you can edit to ignore the ssl error.

Comment: Which is this class?

Comment: ```SystemWebViewClient```, you can modify the ```onReceivedSslError``` and put the ```handler.proceed();```on the first line

Answer (score 4):

You can use this Plugin to allow untrusted certificates:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-certificates

When your app starts just call:

```
cordova.plugins.certificates.trustUnsecureCerts(true);
```

Comment: can you help me where to call this function.

Comment: You can run it in the onDeviceReady function.

Comment: thank you very much. this method save me from my headache when already specify CSP and install plugin whitelist also. but still cannot use AJAX request. while in debug mode is no problem. you ROCK!!!